# Define or Declare

Tags: c++, arduino

I have been working with code from several sources and notice that some coders prefer to `#define`, while others prefer to declare a `const`.

For example:

```
#define A_CONSTANT 3
```

or:

```
const int A_CONSTANT = 3;
```

In this simply a preference, **or does it make an actual difference in the resulting code/compile time/other**?  My understanding is that the `#define` is a pre-processor directive, which results in a `3` being substituted wherever `A_CONSTANT` is found, while the declaration allocates a byte (or two) of memory and a reference to that location wherever `A_CONSTANT` is used, and that the difference would be very slight, if there is any difference at all.

Comment: What programming language are you using? please tag.

Comment: this is mostly based on opinion and personal preference. you'll find many discussions on what is better. most of them full of false facts. there are differences and both have their use cases. the main difference would be that you can redefine a macro anywhere in the code and that constants are scoped. please note that `const int A_CONSTANT = 3;` is also a definition in C++ terminology.

Comment: @Raymond Chen: The tag `arduino` implies C++

Comment: It's up to the compiler's optimizing stategy, whether it will `allocate a byte (or two) of memory and a reference to that location wherever A_CONSTANT is used`. Usually there will be no difference in the compiled code, but error handling can be better with `const` declarations.

Comment: @datafiddler It depends on whether you are trying to program the arduino or communicate with it. You can communicate with the arduino in a variety of languages, [such as C#](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/9bf6501a31fa0cfff31cae428bcdbeb49c8f2766/Samples/SerialArduino/README.md).

Comment: Compiled code will usually be the same, but there are also things like scoping and typing to be considered.